# Botman Studio conversation_cache_time

Tags: php, eloquent, laravel-5

I'm doing a chatbot in the telegram API with Botman Studio that integrates laravel and php. I want to count the time the user uses the chatbot.

When the user types "/ start" the conversation with the bot starts:

[image]

I want from there to start counting the time to enter it into my database in order to know how long users interact with the chatbot.

How could I do this in my conversations?

```html
<?php

return [

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Conversation Cache Time
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | BotMan caches each started conversation. This value defines the
    | number of minutes that a conversation will remain stored in
    | the cache.
    |
    */
    'conversation_cache_time' => 1,

    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | User Cache Time
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | BotMan caches user information of the incoming messages.
    | This value defines the number of minutes that this
    | data will remain stored in the cache.
    |
    */
    'user_cache_time' => 1,
];
```

Here I establish that after a minute of inactivity, the conversation stops, I want that at the same time that the conversation in the database is stopped the time is stored. How could I establish a condition for it?

Answer (score 0):

Well, if you have a way to know that user quit the conversation, you can store the datetime of when user started a conversation and store datetime of when user ended the conversation. Then if you want to know how much user spent, just subtract endDate - beginDate. You can use Carbon to make your life easier when manipulating Datetimes

Comment: I already use carbon to store the date and time, the problem is how to insert the time in my database when conversation_cache_time stops the conversation due to inactivity, how can I get the value of "conversation_cache_time" and pass it to a condition.